# Html.BeginForm() is not returning value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Html.BeginForm() is not returning value to from  @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Number); to  controller, in book is exactly the same and there it work, what is wrong ?

```
@model FrizzBuzz1.Models.dane
....
<body>
    <div class="panel-body"> 
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Number);
        }
        <input class="btn-success" type="submit" value="Wyslij" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Index(dane Dane)
 {

    if (Dane.Number % 3 == 0 && Dane.Number % 5 != 0)
    {
        Dane.napis = "Fizz";
    }
    else if(Dane.Number % 5 == 0 && Dane.Number % 3 != 0)
    {
        Dane.napis = "Buzz";
    }
    else if (Dane.Number % 5 == 0 && Dane.Number % 3 == 0)
    {
        Dane.napis = "FizzBuzz";
    }
    else 
    {
        Dane.napis = "Nic";
    }
   return View("Index", Dane);
}
```

Model

```
public class dane
{
    public int Number;
    public string napis;
}
```

Comment: Show your model

Comment: namespace FrizzBuzz1.Models
{
    public class dane
    {
        public int Number;
        public string napis;
        
    }
}

Comment: Edit your question (not in commnets). And your model has fields only, not properties - add `{ get; set; }` - the `DefaultModelBinder` does not bind fields